# extjs form and html attribute

Tags: forms, extjs, rendering

I have one extjs `form`.

Most of the contents are set to the `form` using the `html` attribute of the form.

Now I need some extjs contents to be appended in the `form` below the `html` components. But when I set, all the extjs `components` are set first and html components are rendering below it.

How will I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to explicitely render your Ext component in a container at the bottom of your form?

For example, you HTML would look like:

```
<form ...>
    <!-- Pure HTML fields -->
    <input type="text" ... />

    <!-- ExtJS fields container -->
    <div id="ext-field-ct"></div>
</form>
```

And, in your Javascript, use the [`renderTo`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo) option or the `render` method of the fields:

```
Ext.widget('textfield', {renderTo: 'ext-field-ct', name: "My Textfield", ...});
```